Spring MVC static resource mapping for favicon.ico both root and suffix matching
I'm using Spring/Spring MVC 4.2.5. In my application exception log I've seen some weird requests for favicon.ico, for example: https://mydomain/path/to/some/webpage/favicon.ico. I've added favicon.ico to:
[1] jsp page layout head section using:
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="<c:url value="/favicon.ico" />"> (c:is just adding application context path, part of JSTL core)
[2] static resource handling mapping:
registry.addResourceHandler(new String[]{"/favicon.ico", "**/favicon.ico"}).addResourceLocations(new String[]{"/resources/"});

Current result:

[A] my website now correctly shows the favicon.ico in browser
[B] if I manually enter URL https://mydomain/favicon.ico I see my favicon.ico picture loaded
[C] if I manually enter URL https://mydomain/some/path/to/any/web/page/favicon.ico I get PAGE NOT FOUND (404)

Desired result:

I want also for [C] to see my favicon.ico picture being loaded instead of 404 page.

Expected pitfall:
Mapping /favicon.ico path to /resources/favicon.ico works as desired
but mapping **/favicon.ico to /resources/favicon.ico doesn't. Resource handler searches for physical resource /resources/path/to/web/page/favicon.ico. I need to "somehow" ignore /path/to/web/page ideally without rewriting the PathResourceResolver - thinking if that is possible with some pattern or so.
Any ideas how to achieve that (don't want to write a separate handler method for it)? Thank you very much.
